# Showing logged in user as the author in Hippo CMS

Tags: hippocms

I have configured Hippo CMS and I am using content (simpleDocument i guess) to show content on my site. I want to get the logged in user as the content author and show it in the website with the content. Currently I am using content blocks and added a text field (author) and i am accessing it with `${document.author?html}` and I saw in cms console that there is a property named createdBy in this path `/hippo:namespaces/hippostdpubwf/document/hipposysedit:nodetype/hipposysedit:nodetype/CreatedBy`I want to know how to access this property through freemarker.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by creating a method in your bean and use getProperty("hippostdpubwf:createdBy")

hth!